# Oracle ADF: LOV not working on create

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf

I have a ViewObject (VO1) with a ListOfValue that points to a ViewObject (VO2), and fetches records from VO2. There is no ViewCriteria added on VO2.
When testing in the BC tester, the LOV works fine. Both on editing a row in VO1, and when creating a row in VO1.

Using the LOV in a jspx page, the LOV works fine when editing a row in VO1. But when I'm creating a new row in the jspx page, the LOV doesn't fetch any records. Just an empty list.
I can't figure out what is wrong, or why it doesn't work. I have created several LOV all working like a charm, but this one is making me tear my hair out.

Anyone else experienced a similar scenario where a LOV only works upon editing a row?
Any ideas what can be wrong?

The SOC on the jspx page:

```
<af:selectOneChoice value="#{row.bindings.IdSosBasGrantType.inputValue}"
label="#{row.bindings.IdSosBasGrantType.label}"
required="#{bindings.SosBasCaseGrantPerCaseType.hints.IdSosBasGrantType.mandatory}"
shortDesc="#{bindings.SosBasCaseGrantPerCaseType.hints.IdSosBasGrantType.tooltip}"
id="soc12" autoSubmit="true">
<f:selectItems value="#{row.bindings.IdSosBasGrantType.items}" id="si11"/>
</af:selectOneChoice>
```

The iterator binding:

```
<tree IterBinding="SosBasCaseGrantPerCaseTypeIterator" id="SosBasCaseGrantPerCaseType">
<nodeDefinition DefName="fo.att.alm.sos.model.bas.views.SosBasCaseGrantVO" Name="SosBasCaseGrantPerCaseType0">
<AttrNames>
<Item Value="Seq"/>
<Item Value="IdSosBasGrantType"/>
<Item Value="IdSosBasGrantVariant"/>
<Item Value="RuleType"/>
<Item Value="Status"/>
<Item Value="IdAplCfgPartyType"/>
</AttrNames>
</nodeDefinition>
</tree>
```

The ViewAttribute:

```
<ViewAttribute
Name="IdSosBasGrantType"
LOVName="LOV_IdSosBasGrantType"
IsUnique="true"
IsNotNull="true"
PrecisionRule="true"
EntityAttrName="IdSosBasGrantType"
EntityUsage="SosBasCaseGrantEO"
AliasName="ID_SOS_BAS_GRANT_TYPE">
<Properties>
<SchemaBasedProperties>
<CONTROLTYPE
Value="choice"/>
</SchemaBasedProperties>
</Properties>
</ViewAttribute>
```

The ListBinding:

```
<ListBinding
Name="LOV_IdSosBasGrantType"
ListVOName="SosBasGrantTypeUsgLOV"
ListRangeSize="-1"
NullValueFlag="none"
NullValueId="LOV_IdSosBasGrantType_LOVUIHints_NullValueId"
MRUCount="0">
<AttrArray Name="AttrNames">
<Item Value="IdSosBasGrantType"/>
</AttrArray>
<AttrArray Name="ListAttrNames">
<Item Value="GrantTypeId"/>
</AttrArray>
<AttrArray Name="ListDisplayAttrNames">
<Item Value="ObjectTypeDisplayName"/>
</AttrArray>
<DisplayCriteria/>
</ListBinding>
```

The ViewAccessor

```
<ViewAccessor
Name="SosBasGrantTypeUsgLOV"
ViewObjectName="fo.att.alm.sos.model.bas.views.SosBasGrantTypeUsgRO"
RowLevelBinds="true"/>
```

Comment: How are you creating the new row?

Comment: With the createInsert action from the ViewObject under Data Controls

Answer (score 0):

Hard to guess without knowing more about the code.
But if you have a situation where on creating a new record the LOV shows up empty, maybe you have a viewlink defined between the two VOs.
You need to make sure that the LOV data comes from an independent VO2 that is not a detail of VO1.

Comment: It's not a cascading LOV, and the LOV data comes from an independet VO2.
And it works in the BC tester

Answer (score 0):

I guess that 
1- Lov view object VO2 has view link defined between two View Objects
2- Lov view object VO2  has parameter in its sql statement to filter data which gets its value from current view object VO1 and the parameter is null so it will not return data

Comment: 1. There is no VL between the VO. Is it even possible to use VL in LOV?
2. The VO behind the lov doesn't take parameters. It fetches all records

Answer (score 0):

Try turning on the ADF BC debugging and see what is the query that the LOV sends to the DB when you invoke it from the page.
edit your project properties and in the Run/Debug page, select a run configuration and click Edit. Then add the string -Djbo.debugoutput=console to the Java Options field.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16162_01/web.1112/e16182/web_testdebug.htm#BABDBCGF

Comment: Both in the BC and when the site is running, the LOV component looks to be correctly initialized, with the same bind variables set.
But the LOV component works in the BC tester, but is empty on the live site.
I have tried to execute the query, and the query returns the correct records. I'm stumbled!